# How to calculate the "Engagement Rate" in GA4 connected to BigQuery?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

### Description

- I have connected the [GA4 to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).
- The GA4 data in bigquery include: `ga_session_id`, `page_location`, `user_pseudo_id`, `session_engaged`, ...
- I want to use python client api to query the data from bigquery.
- Then use the data from bigquery to calculate the `engagement rate` for each page like GA4  report.

### Try

According to the [defination of `engagement rate`](https://measureschool.com/ga4-metrics/):

`engagement_rate = engaged_session_nums / session_nums * 100%`

I have create a dataframe which include `ga_session_id`, `page_location`, `user_pseudo_id`, `session_engaged`, and the `session_engaged` is a booling type.

I use the following code to calculate `engagement rate`:

(**not sure `engaged_session_nums` how to calculate**)

```py
# the session = ga_session_id + user_pseudo_id
df['pseudo_with_session'] = df['ga_session_id'].astype(str) + df['user_pseudo_id']

# not sure engaged_session_nums how to calculate
df['engaged_session_nums'] = df.groupby(['page_location'])['session_engaged'].transform(lambda x: (x == '1').sum())

# calculate the session nums for each page
df['total_session_nums'] = df.groupby('page_location')['pseudo_with_session'].transform('nunique')

df['engaged_rate'] = df['engaged_session_nums'] / df['total_session_nums'] * 100
```

### Results

The result get over 100%, and very different with GA4 report.

| page_location | engagement_rate |
| --- | --- |
| / | 26.2% |
| /en/ | 117% |
| ... | ... |

### Expected (GA4 report)

| page_location | engagement_rate |
| --- | --- |
| / | 75.22% |
| /en/ | 73.34% |
| ... | ... |

Comment: GA4 is event-based, if you sum by page_location, it might be lots of valid events (engaged), 
and on the homepage, the user clicks and is redirected to another page which makes that page not count as engaged on that page.

Answer (score 0):

to calculate the ratio of the number of sessions a user was engaged in to the maximum session number for each user.

Summing session_engaged(The value will be 0 if there is no engaged sessions, and 1 if there is an engaged session. for each user_pseudo_id from session_start events.
Finding the maximum session_number for each user_pseudo_id from session_start events. (It counts the number of sessions for specific user_pseudo_id )
Dividing the total session_engaged by the maximum session_number for each user.
here is what you want :

```html
WITH session_data AS (
    SELECT
        user_pseudo_id,
        (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
        MAX((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_number')) AS max_session_number,
        SUM((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'session_engaged')) AS total_session_engaged
    FROM
        `dataset_id`
    WHERE
        event_name = 'session_start'
    GROUP BY
        user_pseudo_id, page_location
)
SELECT
    page_location,
    100 - AVG(IF(max_session_number = 0, 0, total_session_engaged / max_session_number * 100)) AS bounce_rate
FROM
    session_data
GROUP BY
    page_location;
```

Comment: I expected get bounce rate for each `page_location`, but this SQL without `GROUPBY page_location`. I think this will get different result with my expected.

Comment: right, I edited my last post, now it's what you expected

Comment: Thanks your reply. However, I tried to use this code, the result still very different with GA4 report. Example `/en/` of bounce rate: `GA4=25.37%` but `BQ=0.0%`